# Capturar y recorrer un arreglo de cadenas en C

Tags: array, c, string, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos

El problema dice que necesito encontrar el segundo elemento más grande de un arreglo de cadenas (con base en su valor ascii). Entiendo perfectamente el problema, sin embargo a la hora de implementar la solución en C vuelvo a tener problemas con el manejo de cosas como punteros y memoria.
El código empieza a correr bien, simplemente que despues de solicitar la segunda palabra del arreglo el programa termina de ejecutarse.
¿Qué está fallando exactamente?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* captura();
void comparacion();

int main()
{
    char* palabras[5][30];

    comparacion(captura(palabras));

    return 0;
}

//Funcion para capturar el arreglo de cadenas
char* captura(char* palabras[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
        gets(palabras[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    return palabras;
}

//Funcion para comparar el arreglo de cadenas
void comparacion(char* palabras[])
{
    int may1, may2;

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Evaluacion de casos
        if(strcmp(palabras[i-1], palabras[i]) > 0)
        {
            may1 = palabras[i-1];
            may2 = palabras[i];
        }
        else if(strcmp(palabras[i-1], palabras[i]) < 0)
        {
            may1 = palabras[i];
            may2 = palabras[i-1];
        }
        else
        {
            may2 = may1;
        }
    }

    printf("La segunda palabra mas grande es: %s", palabras[may2]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando te dedicas a programar, un detalle importantísimo es aprender a leer los mensajes que salen cuando compilas.

El compilador se encarga de convertir texto plano en instrucciones máquinas y, por el camino, es capaz de ver cosas que no están bien ... ahí es cuando empieza a imprimir advertencias y errores.

El primer error que tienes, para tu desgracia, no te lo marca el compilador:

```
char* palabras[5][30];
```

En esa linea has declarado un puntero que puede direccionar matrices de tipo `char`. El problema es que es eso, un puntero. Ahí no has creado ninguna matriz de 5x30. El puntero no está inicializado, luego apunta a memoria aleatoria y cualquier intento de acceder a esa memoria puede ser catastrófico.

Tienes que quitar ese puntero y dejarlo así:

```
char palabras[5][30];
```

De esta forma ya sí que se creará el array.

Volviendo ahora ya si a los warnings del compilador, y teniendo en cuenta que únicamente me centraré en los warnings más peligrosos, tenemos que el primer warning sería el siguiente:

> prog.c:27:12: warning: returning 'char **' from a function with incompatible return type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
> 27 |     return palabras;
>         |           ^~~~~~~~

El mensaje es muy claro: `palabras` es de tipo `char**` pero la función dice que devuelve `char*`.

Hay que tener mucho cuidado con los punteros, pues manejarlos mal implica acceder a posiciones incorrectas de memoria y eso nunca te va a dar buenos resultados.

Este warning es especialmente delicado por cómo se gestionan los arrays multidimensionales en C. En este lenguaje, las diferentes filas se encuentran en orden secuencial en la memoria. Así, la siguiente variable:

```
int array[][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

Sirve para declarar el siguiente array:

```
| 1 2 3 |
| 4 5 6 |
```

Y en memoria se encontrará así:

```
| 1 2 3 4 5 6 |
```

No hay ninguna marca de inicio o final de fila o columna. Es responsabilidad del compilador el calcular la posición correcta cuando tu escribes algo tal que:

```
array[1][2] = 55;
```

Pero claro, para que el compilador pueda calcular correctamente esas coordenadas necesita conocer los tamaños del array. El único tamaño que no necesita es el de la primera dimensión del array. Esto es así porque esa dimensión solo sirve para saber cuándo estarías accediendo a un elemento que no pertenece al array, pero C **nunca** va a comprobar eso.

Por otro lado, si declaras el array usando memoria dinámica:

```
int ** array = (int**)malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));
for( int i=0; i<2; i++)
    array[i] = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

La estructura del array ya cambia. Ahora en `array[0]` y `array[1]` tendrás sendos punteros a otras regiones de memoria. Las filas ya no se encuentran en posiciones correlativas de la memoria.

Así que, como ves, los arrays hay que tratarlos con sumo cuidado.

La firma de la función debería quedar, por tanto, así:

```
char [][30] captura(char [][30]);
```

Peero eso no te va a funcionar. C no te permite devolver un array así tan alegremente. Lo más sencillo en tu caso sería que `captura` no devolviese nada y actualizar `main`:

```
captura(palabras);
comparacion(palabras);
```

Nota que deberías poner los parámetros también en la declaración. Si no los pones, el compilador podría tratar algunos errores como warnings, ya que en C, una función que no tiene parámetros (ni `void`), en principio podría recibir cualquier cosa:

```
void func();     // Esta función podría aceptar cualquier cantidad y tipo de parámetros
void func(void); // Esta función no admite parámetros
void func(int);  // Esta función acepta un único parámetro de tipo entero
```

Siguiente warning:

> prog.c:40:18: warning: assignment to 'int' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> 40 |             may1 = palabras[i-1];
>      |          ^

Teniendo en cuenta que `may1` es de tipo `int`:

```
int may1, may2;
```

Te puedes hacer una idea del despropósito de esa línea. Si lo que quieres es almacenar en `may` el índice de una cadena tienes que guardar `i-1`:

```
may = i-1;
```

Si, en cambio, esperas guardar la cadena en sí, cambia el tipo de `may1`:

```
char* may1, may2;
```

Por resumir, el código con los cambios aplicados quedaría así:

```
void captura(char palabras[][30]);
void comparacion(char palabras[][30]);

int main()
{
    char palabras[5][30];
    
    captura(palabras);
    comparacion(palabras);

    return 0;
}

//Funcion para capturar el arreglo de cadenas
void captura(char palabras[][30])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
        gets(palabras[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}

//Funcion para comparar el arreglo de cadenas
void comparacion(char palabras[][30])
{
    int may1, may2;

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Evaluacion de casos
        if(strcmp(palabras[i-1], palabras[i]) > 0)
        {
            may1 = i-1;
            may2 = i;
        }
        else if(strcmp(palabras[i-1], palabras[i]) < 0)
        {
            may1 = i;
            may2 = i-1;
        }
        else
        {
            may2 = may1;
        }
    }

    printf("La segunda palabra mas grande es: %s", palabras[may2]);
}
```

Comment: Corrección: `char* palabras[5][30];` es una matriz de 5x30 de punteros.

Comment: No sé ni cómo agradecerte. Excelsa respuesta